# pandas online logging with resample/timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a log of when users log in and out. I would like to create a log that shows if a particular user is online in a particular fifteen minute window.

pandas has different datetime indexing options (date_range, period_range), but I was using something like `pd.date_range(start, stop, freq)`, but I don't know where to do from there.

Here's the data:

```
user    start                      stop
Alice   2017-10-02 08:59:40-04:00   2017-10-02 09:25:49-04:00
Joe     2017-10-02 08:59:45-04:00   2017-10-02 10:45:11-04:00
Bob     2017-10-02 09:16:06-04:00   2017-10-02 10:05:53-04:00
```

Here's what I need (0 is offline, 1 is online):

```
period            Alice Joe Bob
2017-10-02 09:00  1     1   0
2017-10-02 09:15  1     1   1
2017-10-02 09:30  0     1   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. First create an empty/zeroed DataFrame for every user/time:

```
In [11]: res = pd.DataFrame({name: 0 for name in df["user"].unique()}, pd.date_range("2017-10-02 09:00", "2017-10-02 11:00", freq="15T"))

In [12]: res
Out[12]:
                     Alice  Bob  Joe
2017-10-02 09:00:00      0    0    0
2017-10-02 09:15:00      0    0    0
2017-10-02 09:30:00      0    0    0
2017-10-02 09:45:00      0    0    0
2017-10-02 10:00:00      0    0    0
2017-10-02 10:15:00      0    0    0
2017-10-02 10:30:00      0    0    0
2017-10-02 10:45:00      0    0    0
2017-10-02 11:00:00      0    0    0
```

Now fill in/set for the times where the user is logged in:

```
In [13]: for _, row in df.iterrows():
     ...:     res.loc[row["start"]:row["stop"], row["user"]] = 1
     ...:

In [14]: res
Out[14]:
                     Alice  Bob  Joe
2017-10-02 09:00:00      1    0    1
2017-10-02 09:15:00      1    0    1
2017-10-02 09:30:00      0    1    1
2017-10-02 09:45:00      0    1    1
2017-10-02 10:00:00      0    1    1
2017-10-02 10:15:00      0    0    1
2017-10-02 10:30:00      0    0    1
2017-10-02 10:45:00      0    0    1
2017-10-02 11:00:00      0    0    0
```

Comment: genius! thank you!
sidenote: iterrows, itertuples, and set_value trip me up, this is much more readable

Comment: @HIramFoster please accept if it solved it for you :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers thanks!